# Error Installing Ubuntu 12.04 on Windows 7

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, windows-7

evebody...
today, I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 X64 in my ASUS X45A notebook. 
I prefer X64 cuz in the notebok's Driver CD, it say's "Support with Windows 7 64 bit only!" and i'am afraid something won't work if i installed the X32 OS. 
And when i installing the Ubuntu directly from Windows 7 (i can't boot into Pendrive cuz my netebook doesn't recognize it, help needed too) i got this error message >> "Could not retrieve the required disk image files"

and here is the Wubi error log >> http://paste.ubuntu.com/5785429/

I'm new to Ubuntu.. so please, help me... i'm planning to use Ubuntu cuz it's easier to developing Android Apps... whoever wants to help me, i really appreciate that :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I have seen in the pastebin, your Ubuntu .iso file is corrupted, re-download it again and try it...
Pss. I don't really recommend you to install Ubuntu with Wubi, it's a whole new thing to install it like that and it can become a pain in the a$$...
Better make a bootable CD...

Hope it helps, if you still have trouble don't forget you can count on the AskUbuntu community!

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it seems some of the files were skipped/corrupt during the download (from the logs I'm assuming you used WUBI to download the files as you ran the installer). I'd suggest you try formatting your USB into a filesystem your OS can read (if possible) and attempt to use unetbootin/Universal USB Installer to create a bootable ISO on it. I realise you're on a netbook so I'm unsure whether you'll have a CD drive to work with.

WUBI is useful for those who find themselves wanting to try Linux but wish not to mess with boot menus, installation media etc but it does come with it's share of problems. Try the download again, preferably on a strong/fast connection and see how it goes but I'd say USB boot would be your best option if you could borrow somebody elses or manage to fix yours.

Comment: thank's for your answer... first, I already format using Unetbootin   to Fat32 file system. and yes, it's readable with my Windows 7... 
second, I have an ASUS X45A which is a notebook and it has a CD Drive... but i want to use USB Flash Drive to Install Ubuntu cuz it's easier and faster...
third, i downloaded it in 300 Kb/S Internet speed and no Pause/resume action and i believe, nothing's wrong with the downloaded ISO cuz when i tried to extract it, it works...
thank's for your answer... :)

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment yet, something to note: When you boot into a live CD for the first time, one of the menu options is to verify the disk. **Always** do this before you install from it. It has saved me hours of time in the past to save from a corrupted disk.

I also recommend looking at the MD5 hashes provided for the iso you download. These can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes), if you use Firefox the downthemall extension can automatically MD5/SHA? hash for you to verify.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but how can i check MD5 Sums on windows? cuz in the link that u gave me, it can only done by running Codes from terminal... i looked in the Iso, and find the md5sum.txt and find random numbers and alphabets...